# I cannot start logstash on my machine. Error message inside

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

The following is the test command from the tutorial:

```
./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

The following is the error.

```
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path //usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
01:55:14.242 [main] FATAL logstash.runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:433:in `validate'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:216:in `validate_value'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:132:in `validate_all'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:131:in `validate_all'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:217:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:185:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}
```

As for the error message part that says:

```
Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.
```

The directory is owned and writable by logstash.

Can anyone suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to start logstash in the sudo mode. That is

```
host@host:~$ sudo su
root@host:/home/host# cd /usr/share/logstash
root@host:/usr/share/logstash# ./bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
16:18:33.959 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000}
16:18:33.996 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
The stdin plugin is now waiting for input:
16:18:34.019 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
Hello
2017-06-10T15:18:43.457Z host Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

the exception message tells you that logstash can't find configure property, so you should add a flag in the command to tell logstash the configure property.and another exception is the logstash can't write something to the /usr/share/logstash/data , you should use 'sudo' to start this command, or you can add the write permission of /usr/share/logstash/data to your account.

logstash version:5.5.2

os version:ubuntu 16.04

the command of starting logstash as flow:

```
sudo bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }' --path.settings=/etc/logstash
```

ps:I install logstash by apt install [the document of install logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.5/installing-xpack.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create logstash-data directory and use `--path.data logstash-data` to use logstash-data in current directory as logstash data dir.

Answer (score 1):

You are meant to run it as `logstash` user and not `root` or any other user - that is why it is owned by `logstash` user. So, please use the following instead:

```
sudo -Hu logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

Where the main part here is running your command as `logstash` user:

```
sudo -Hu logstash <command you want to run>
```